# Inno Download Plugin - Compiler error

Tags: plugins, inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

I have been using the IDP plugin for quite some time now, but after installing the latest v1.4.0 I get the following compiler error.

```
Compiling [Code] section
Compiler Error!
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Download Plugin\idp.iss Line 54: Column 55: Unknown type 'Int64'
```

I am currently using Inno Setup 5.5.2 (u).  Can you please assist?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Int64` data type was introduced in Unicode version 5.5.3 so you must download a more recent version of Unicode Inno Setup. [`What's new list`](http://jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm) mentions it like (emphasized by me):

> **5.5.3 (2013-01-30)**
>
> **Unicode Inno Setup: Now has an Int64 type**, supported by IntToStr. Also
>   added new StrToInt64, StrToInt64Def, and GetSpaceOnDisk64 support
>   functions.

Comment: Wow that was fast! Issue solved after installing the latest Inno 5.5.5. Thanks ;)